# Message Passing Chrome API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-api, content-script

I know this has been asked before on here. Unfortunately I can't seem to figure out the chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener.

Here is what I'm sending from my content script (gpa is a variable):

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({gpa});
```

How would I receive that in my background.js file? The google documents I was looking at were only talking about sending responses, I want to save gpa as a variable in background.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({myVar: gpa}); //you have to send an object
```

**background.js**

```
var myBackgroundVar;

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
    if (message.myVar) {
        myBackgroundVar = message.myVar;
    }
});
```

Comment: If I wanted to change the popup.html with background.js would I use send message or could I just change the DOM?